# a id= as aposed to a href=

Tags: css, html, href

I've a nicely layed out unlisted list with links using `<a href="">`, but when I add one link that requires `<a id="">` the CSS ignores it.

As CSS only defines the attributes using `li a:link{}`, how do I get it to recognise the the id= too?

The id=swishLink is used a number of times throughout the site, so I cant really make any changes to swishyLink attributes.

I've tried the `<div id=>` option, but it means I have to create a CSS rule for each list item.

```css
li:first-child a:link{
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 2em;
  border-top-left-radius: 2em;
}
li{
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid white
}
li a:link{
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 200px;
  height:auto;
  padding: 20px;
  display: list-item;
  background: #eefbe7;
  font-family: Arial Rounded MT Bold,Helvetica Rounded,Arial,sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
}
li a:visited{
  color: green;
}
li a:active{
  color:purple;
}
li:last-child a:link{
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2em;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2em;
}
/*
 Change the link color on hover */

 li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="./"> One </a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a id='swishyLink'> Two </a>
        </li>

        <li>
        <a href="./"> Three </a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="./">  Four </a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="./">  five </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: _"The :link CSS pseudo-class represents an element that has not yet been visited. It matches every unvisited <a>, <area>, or <link> element that **has an href attribute**."_ [:link - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/CSS/:link)

Answer (score 3):

If you want your CSS to also apply to `<a>` tags that aren't links, you shouldn't tell it to only apply to links.

It sounds like you don't want `:link`.

Answer (score 1):

`a:link` is backfiring on you. Just use `li a`

```css
li:first-child a{
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 2em;
  border-top-left-radius: 2em;
}
li{
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid white
}
li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 200px;
  height:auto;
  padding: 20px;
  display: list-item;
  background: #eefbe7;
  font-family: Arial Rounded MT Bold,Helvetica Rounded,Arial,sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
}
li a:visited{
  color: green;
}
li a:active{
  color:purple;
}
li:last-child a{
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2em;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2em;
}
/*
 Change the link color on hover */

 li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="./"> One </a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a id='swishyLink'> Two </a>
        </li>

        <li>
        <a href="./"> Three </a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="./">  Four </a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="./">  five </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```